# Setting A Timer On A User Giving Input

Tags: java, timer

Alright, so I've looked at every other thread about this topic, but I'm still unable to get this working for my program...

So I'm coding a card game that's heavily reliant on the users responding quickly. I want to make a method that can be reused infinitely where when given a string parameter, it 'asks' the user the string, then sets a limit on the time they have to respond. From there I want the rest of the program to go on as usual then be able to use the method again. Obviously, this isn't all my code. There's usually more within the while loop, but this is the gist.

```
public static Scanner playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public static boolean gameOver = false;

public static void main(String args[])
{
   while(gameOver = false)
   {
      tooLong("What card are you going to play Player 1: ");
   }
}

public static void tooLong(String s)
{
   TimerTask tooLong = new TimerTask()
   {
      public void run()
      {
         if(playerInput.equals(""))
         {
            System.out.println("Penalty Card Given: Taking Too Long");
         }
      }
   };

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(tooLong, 3000);
   System.out.print(s);
   playerInput = input.next();
   timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: So what doesn't work about your code?

Comment: It only works the first time through, any other instance just doesn't have a time limit; it'll just stay on the prompt and never say "Penalty Card Given"